# How to print a 2d list in python3

Tags: python-3.x

So this is printing output on different lines for each i and j, but what i want is for each i only.

```
import sys

n,m = map(int,sys.stdin.readline().split())

i,j=0,0

a=[[0]*m]*n

for i in range(0,n):
    for j in range(0,m):
        a[i][j]=input()

i,j=0,0

for i in range(n):
    for j in range(m):
        if(a[i][j] == '.'):
            if((i+j)&1 == 0):
                print('B\t'),
            else:
                print('W\t'),
        else:
            print('-')
```

Comment: use `print('text', end='')`

Answer (score 0):

Use `print('text', end='')` to keep text in one line and `print()` to go in new line.

Your code could look like this:

```
import sys

n, m = map(int, sys.stdin.readline().split())

array = []

for i in range(n):
    row = []
    for j in range(m):
        row.append( input() )
    array.append( row )

for y, row in enumerate(array):
    for x, cell in enumerate(row):
        if cell == '.':
            if (x+y)&1 == 0:
                print('B\t', end='')
            else:
                print('W\t', end='')
        else:
            print('-', end='')
    print()
```